# clang-tidy 'iosfwd' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]

Tags: c++, bazel, clang-tidy

i build my repo with bazel_clang_tidy,but meet some question,always report error: 'iosfwd' file not found

```
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_google_glog/_virtual_includes/glog/glog/logging.h:42:10: error: 'iosfwd' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <iosfwd>
         ^
Aspect @bazel_clang_tidy//clang_tidy:clang_tidy.bzl%clang_tidy_aspect of //es_cpp:main-es failed to build
```

I don't have any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: You have error in logging.h file. Can you try " bazel clean --expunge" and rebuild the application.

Comment: i try it.It doesn't work